# Route to method always uses first listed despite different name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and trying to create up / down vote buttons (implemented as text links for now for clarity). However no matter which link is clicked it calls the action of the first link despite the different names.

I've read over and over the docs and answers on here and wrestled with it all day but still can't understand why rails can't see the difference, any help greatly appreciated.

Routes

```
Futurebot::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

resources :posts do
       member do
         post 'delete'
         post 'upVote'
         post 'downVote'
  end
end


match ':posts/:id/:upVote', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'upVote'
match ':posts/:id/:downVote', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'downVote'
```

If I remove the resources :posts block it can't find the route but it seems like the match statements should work (that's what the url looks like)

view

```
<%= link_to "up: ", :action => 'upVote', :id => post.id %>
<%= link_to "down: ", :action => 'downVote', :id => post.id %>
```

controller

```
  def upVote
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.increment!(:score)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end
  end

    def downVote
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.decrement!(:score)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end
  end

rake routes: with the 2 new routes commented out (so just the block is there)

     up_vote_post POST   /posts/:id/up_vote(.:format)                posts#up_vo
te
   down_vote_post POST   /posts/:id/down_vote(.:format)              posts#down_
vote
                  GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index

                  POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#creat
e
                  GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
                  GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
                  GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                  PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#updat
e
                  DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destr
oy
             root        /    

                                   posts#index
```

Rake routes with two routes in routes.rb

```
      delete_post POST   /posts/:id/delete(.:format)                 posts#delet
e
     up_vote_post POST   /posts/:id/up_vote(.:format)                posts#up_vo
te
   down_vote_post POST   /posts/:id/down_vote(.:format)              posts#down_
vote
                  GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index

                  POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#creat
e
                  GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
                  GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
                  GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                  PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#updat
e
                  DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destr
oy
                         /:post/up_vote/:id(.:format)                post#up_vot
e
                         /:post/down_vote/:id(.:format)              post#down_v
ote
             root        /    

                                   posts#index
```

The added routes

```
match ':post/up_vote/:id' => "post#up_vote"
match ':post/down_vote/:id' => "post#down_vote"
```

**UPDATE**

strangely if I change the route around to:

```
match ':post/:id/up_vote/' => "post#up_vote"
match ':post/:id/down_vote/' => "post#down_vote"
```

..as that looks like the link then the error is

```
uninitialized constant PostController
```

I've tried using both post and posts based on the solution to that in another question

Comment: can you provide the output of your `rake routes`?

Comment: @LeoCorrea added, some bits reference the answer below as it seems like it should work but still isn't.

Comment: What is your controller called? Your match should be named like this `match 'post/:id/up_vote' => "posts#up_vote"` Its plural on the posts for the matching part but again, I don't advice using that.

Comment: Can you also post your updated view code and your complete controller code?

Comment: You legend :) the problem was using "post#up_vote# instead of "posts#up_vote" i.e. it needed to be plural. Why do you advise against using it? Is it easier to use github that posting long streams of code here or is that considered bad etiquette? The code is here if it help:
 
https://github.com/mwhammond/futurebot

Comment: I don't advice using match without a specific http method defined. `match '/posts/:id/up_vote' => "posts#up_vote", via: :post` is fine, you can even define multiple methods like `match '/posts/:id/up_vote' => "posts#up_vote", via: [:post, :get]` but match without a http method is deprecated and its bad practice because it pretty much leaves up to any http method.

Comment: My question was why are you using `:posts/:id/up_vote` ? as opposed to `posts/:id/up_vote`. Are you using the params[:posts] in any way? The only reason I ask is that say you have a url that looks like this http://somedomain.com/hello/1/up_vote it will still be matched to that route because :post is just part of a 'slug'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    post 'delete' 
    post 'up_vote'
    post 'down_vote'
  end
end
```

should give you a routes output similar to this

```
POST /posts/:id/delete(.:format)
     /posts/:id/up_vote(.:format)
     /posts/:id/down_vote(.:format)
```

And they should map out to the `PostsController` and its respective actions `delete`, `up_vote`, `down_vote`.

Is there any reason why you have those two match routes at the end? They pretty much look like wildcards to me and I don't think you need them.

What is really happening is that anything that matches the following

```
something/another/path
```

will get mapped to those routes, specifically to the first one and it will be split in the params like

```
params[:posts] => something
params[:id]    => another
params[:upVote]=> path
```

That happens because you are using the colon character which allows you to specify dynamic routes. For example something like this

```
match 'hello/world/:name' => "hello#say"
```

would get mapped out to a `HelloController` and action `say`. Inside the action you would then have `params[:name]` that would be equal to whatever is under name.

So `hello/world/leo` would have `params[:name]` equal to leo

For more information take a look at this: [Rails Routes: Dynamic Segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments)

**NOTE** Also, try not to use camel case for method names in Ruby :D

**UPDATE** You need a `:method => "post"` on your `link_to` in order for it to send a post request

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed response. If I understand correctly it should work then? The extra routes are there to see if I can 'force' it, I just tried changing them based on the description above but it still fails. The error is No route matches [GET] "/posts/196/up_vote" which makes me wonder why GET is being used especially after adding :method => post to the view. I'll edit in the updated routes and rake routes output in a few moments. Thanks so much for your help.